# Network configuration on boot taking longer than 60 seconds... why?

Tags: boot, networking, nvidia, dhcp

My HTPC was running Ubuntu 13.04 and had no problems, but I've re-formatted the system and installed Ubuntu 14.04 (minimal) from scratch and I've having a problem with my network.

When the system boots, I see the Plymouth Ubuntu logo and after about 15 seconds it says "Waiting for network configuration..." (or something similar) and it takes around 60+ seconds before it continues.

I have around 10 machines on my network and my DHCP server works perfectly with every other client so this issue is specific to my HTPC.

The hardware is an older Gigabyte GA-E7AUM-DS2H motherboard using a NVIDIA MCP79 chipset.  (forcedeth network driver)

Can anybody give me any information on how to troubleshoot or fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Fast Link (aka Portfast, etc) was disabled on my switch for this port by accident.

After enabling it everything is working perfectly.

Comment: So, can you close your question?